# Autocomplete in the middle of text field Android

Tags: android, textview, autocompletetextview

I am making an SMS application similar to the android sms.
In the "TO" field of the compose sms feature, I want to enter contacts from contact list. I am able to enter for the 1st contact. But for the 2nd contact it does not autocomplete. How to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the MultiAutoCompleteTextView for this.It worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 workarounds:

1. Make an `Add` button next to the text field, which pops up a dialog with autocomplete. When return, add the name to the contact field.
2. Dynamically create a new text field for each contact to be added by clicking an `add` button on the same page. Put a `remove` button next to each text field.